# A pluripolar set that disconnects an open?

Tags: cv.complex-variables, potential-theory

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded open set of $\mathbb{C}^{n}$, and $F$ a pluripolar subset of $\mathbb{C}^{n}$. We know that if $F$ is closed, then $\Omega\setminus F$ is a connected open set. What if $F$ is not closed? Is $\Omega\setminus F$ still a connected set?

Comment: From a probabilistic heuristic, it should still be connected.  Given two nonempty disjoint open sets $U, V \subset \Omega$, there is a positive probability that a Brownian motion started in $U$ reaches $V$ in time 1.  And there is zero probability that the Brownian motion hits $F$.  Since the Brownian motion is continuous, $U,V$ cannot disconnect $\Omega \setminus F$.

Comment: Is there a more analytical way to prove it?

Comment: If I knew how to do that, I'd have posted an answer :)  But hopefully someone else will.

Comment: You just need the case of $n=1$. The intersection of a complex line with a pluripolar set either the entire line or a polar set. Now consider a line through two points in $\Omega\setminus F$.

Comment: Can you please explain why just n=1?